# Boost::asio async_read simple file upload

Tags: javascript, html, c++, boost-asio

I'm trying to create a simple file upload using boost::asio and ajax. Somehow the bytes_transferred reaches a maximum at 21845 (or something like that) even though my buffer size is 500MB. With text files std::cout displays something but with binary files it cuts off right after the header (still 21845 bytes are transferred).

I tried using different methods like async_read_some and async_read_until but it didn't change anything. Also tried socket.set_option() with keep-alive and changing socket buffer size.

```
class tcp_connection
{
public:
void start() {
    boost::asio::async_read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(buf), boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1), boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handler, error, bytes_transferred));
}
private:
boost::array<unsigned char, 500000000> buf;
void handler(error, bytes) {
    std::cout << buf.data() << std::endl;

    boost::asio::async_write(socket, response_buffer, boost::bind(&tcp_connection, handler));
}
}
```

Please look at https://pastebin.com/dPvVGsjU for the full minimal-reproductible example

I don't receive error messages, although I am ignoring eof errors.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you suppose that the whole data will be read during one read operation ? Your completion condition is `transfer_at_least(1)`, so read operation can read 1, 10, 100 or N bytes and return. You should read data until the whole content is received. Because you don't know the length of input data, you continue reading until `eof` occures.

So logic of handler passed into `async_read` should be:

```
void send_response2(const boost::system::error_code& err, const size_t& bytes) 
{
    if (err == boost::asio::error::eof)
    {
        // analyze your buf2 here if it is what you wanted to read
        // here you can start sending data
    }
    else if (err)
    { /* problem */ }
    else 
    {
        // call again async_read with send_response like
        boost::asio::async_read(socket, boost::asio::dynamic_buffer(buf2), boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1), boost::bind(&tcp_connection::send_response2, shared_from_this(),
                                                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
}
```

---

Instead of `buffer::array` as buffer with fixed size, you can use [dynamic buffer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/dynamic_buffer.html). Then your buffer will be extended, by adding new read bytes.

```
std::string buf2; // as data member
// then pass buffer by
boost::asio::dynamic_buffer(buf2)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your solution, but I tried it and it seems that no response is sent at all from the server. Since you wrote send_response2 do you mean that this is a second handler or is this directly after the first read operation? Could it be that eof is not sent by the browser?

Comment: Basically what is happening now is that no eof is sent. Instead, It goes to the second read operation and just waits for  at least 1 byte, which never arrives. Tried doing this with async_read_some but that didn't work either.

Comment: What is the format of reading data? Does it have some a header with the length of the entire input?

Comment: When I upload a .png it just shows <?>PNG [o] (imagine binary). I guess that is the PNG header. The browser sends the content length which is a lot larger that 21845 but doesn't send a continue header. It's not only binary: When I upload a text file that is longer than 21845 it gets cut off at 21845 bytes. Could it have to do with hardware?

Comment: Also, the handler (send_response) doesn't seem to be called at all when a file such as a .png is being uploaded.